# JavaFX - Why does changing the header text of a dialog make the button bar invisible?

Tags: java, javafx, dialog

Here is a small sample from my custom dialog, which is meant to display the progress of a running `javafx.concurrent.Task`.

```java
DialogPane pane = this.getDialogPane()
pane.getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.CANCEL);

pane.headerTextProperty().bind(task.titleProperty());
pane.contentTextProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
```

For some reason, the buttons in the button bar disappeared, but only after some text updated. After further investigation, I found that binding the header text of a dialog seems to remove all the buttons in the button bar. Why would this happen, and what would I do to stop the buttons from being hidden?

EDIT: Here's an MCVE demonstrating the problem.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MCVE extends Application {
  public static class CustomDialog extends Dialog<ButtonType> {

    public CustomDialog(Task<?> task) {
      this.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

      DialogPane pane = this.getDialogPane();
      {
        pane.getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.CANCEL);
        pane.headerTextProperty().bind(task.titleProperty());
      }

      setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
        if (task.isRunning()) event.consume();
      });
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Button starter = new Button("Showcase");
    starter.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

    root.getChildren().add(starter);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();


    starter.setOnAction(event -> {
      Task<Void> task = new Task<>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
          updateTitle("Before loop");
          try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            if (isCancelled()) return null;
          }
          for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            updateTitle("loop " + i);

            try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
              if (isCancelled()) return null;
            }
          }
          return null;
        }
      };
      Thread worker = new Thread(task);

      worker.start();
      new CustomDialog(task).showAndWait();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: hmm .. cannot reproduce: the cancel button is always there, just not visible because the dialog is not large enough (make it resizable to see), so it looks more like a layout problem. What am I missing?

Comment: Ah. I thought the cancel button had just randomly disappeared out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue needs fixing on JavaFX's end. In fact, the button bar is simply pushed out of view. There is a relatively decent workaround though. `Dialog` internally uses a styled `GridPane` to display header text and graphics, so I simply replicated that using an external `GridPane` and instead bound to the `textProperty()` of a `Label`.

```java
  public static class CustomDialog extends Dialog<ButtonType> {
    public CustomDialog(Task<?> task) {
      DialogPane pane = this.getDialogPane(); {
        pane.getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.CANCEL);
        //construct custom header
        GridPane headerRoot = new GridPane(); {
          Label headerText = new Label();
          //headerText is the label containing the header text
          headerText.textProperty().bind(task.titleProperty());

          headerRoot.add(headerText, 0, 0);
        }
        headerRoot.getStyleClass().addAll("header-panel");
        pane.setHeader(headerRoot);

        pane.setContentText("Placeholder content");

        pane.getScene().getWindow().setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
          if (!task.isDone()) {
            event.consume();
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

It looks exactly the same as a default dialog, without the issue mentioned in the question above.